# How to delete all of the Instant Upload photos on Google+?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

I managed to disable Instant Upload, but it already pumped hundreds of photos from my iPad to my Google+ account. I'd like to delete them en masse. I can't find a simple way.

I can drag a selection, but it's very slow to scroll down in Chrome (the pictures are big in the Instant Upload view, G+ slowly scrolls the selection down). I can't find a way in the iPad/iPodTouch version of G+ either... [This thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plus-discuss/XHjLUNoDeco) addresses the issue, but I can't make sense of it (perhaps on the Android version it's obvious?).

Comment: Thank you... was doing that and did not see an option to delete and then realized that it was at the top of the page. If I started to lasso from the bottom up then the delete button is right there! I fee stupid.. hahah anyway, just wanted to show some appreciation for your post.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I did some experimenting, although I didn't actually delete the photos (since I want to keep them). But I was able to select them all.

I'm using Chrome on Windows 7.

1. Open "Instant Upload" under your Google+ Photos
2. Hit the <kbd>End</kbd> key. Your browser window will scroll down to the bottom of what's currently displayed. Google+ will load up more photos. Hit <kbd>End</kbd> again. Repeat as necessary.
3. Click and drag from below and to the right of your photos to start selecting them. You'll have a shaded box to guide you. Start painting up and to the left to start selecting photos.
4. **Without releasing the mouse button** hit the <kbd>Home</kbd> key to scroll all the way back up to the top. You should be able to fine-tune the select area to capture all of the photos.
5. Click the "Delete" button (only visible at the top of the page).

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Error message is shown on top: `Failed to delete photos. Please try again`. But apparently deleted after some time.

Comment: Works with Firefox too.

Comment: `Sorry, but you can't select more than 2000 photos.` Use Page Up button to select 2k, then repeat.

Comment: This really sucks - such a steptoe solution. Perhaps you could close the photos account and reopen?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem as the OP: Google+ had uploaded 800MB of photos on my mobile without prompting me. Here is the solution I've found to delete whole album, which was not available in Google+ interface. Open https://picasaweb.google.com/home, there you'll see the instant upload photo album and the option to delete the whole album.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for this link. I saw these weird old random pictures appearing in my Album on Android, then with effort I found out it had something to do with Instant Upload (I don't even have a Google+ account, these are probably old Picasa uploads?). I searched for some way to log into Picasa online, but couldn't find it. Thanks to your link, I was able to delete those weird old albums; now I my Gallery on my phone just shows me my real folders I want, great!