# How can I download all photos from Instant Upload (Auto Backup)?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

I've been uploading via Instant Upload (a.k.a Auto Backup) from my Android phone now for about a year. There are many photos and now I want to download them all to my computer. However, I can't download them all because they are not in an album and I can't move all to an album since there is no way to "Mark All/Every photo".

So how could I solve this?

Comment: The technique in [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/28531/354) should allow you to select all of the images relatively painlessly.

Comment: @AlEverett, that worked really well. I didn't know that you could select photos by dragging a box around them. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Visit [Google Takeout](https://www.google.com/takeout/). It’s a service by Google where you can download "all" your data of any Google service. 
Choose **"Google Photos"**. This should contain all your uploaded images.

Comment: Choose "Google+ Photos" now.  Works great.

Comment: Can an OP or admin mark this as best answer? Just used Google Takeout and it works great!

Comment: I hope this works for me too, I have like 40Gb of photos (a lot of our wedding and then the last 14 yrs on there too). I do have local copies but we are trying to ensure we have a copy of everything everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

To finish of the thread: According to [Al Everett](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/al-everett):

In [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28529/how-to-delete-all-of-the-instant-upload-photos-on-google/28531#28531) you can find a way to select all photos in Instant Upload. Instead of Deleting them you can add them to an album and afterwards download the entire album.

Comment: The technique to select all photos does not currently work with Google+ photos.  But Google Takeout (above) works well.