# How do you delete instant uploads on Android phones lined to Picasa?

Tags: picasa-web-albums

I have a Virgin Mobile Kyocera Rise phone. There is an album called instant uploads with the little Picasa symbol. How do I delete that album?

When I select it all it lets me do is share. It also sends all those pictures automatically to a Google+ account. I deleted them from that account online but it's still on my phone. I want to get rid of it all together but don't know how.

Comment: See [this](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/28529/1512) question as well.