# How to delete all the Google+ stories (auto-awesome images) created while backing up from Android

Tags: google-plus, android, image-storage

I enabled recently the backing up of my images/videos on my Android 4.4 Nexus 5 since it was suggested to me, as described here http://techcrunch.com/2014/02/25/google-quietly-begins-pushing-its-photo-backup-software-to-google-users/

Backups only occur when I'm charging (at home, to save bandwidth) and I have hundreds of photos since about 6 months ago. The process is slow (and not completed as of writing this).

What's annoying me is that Google+ is creating stories and auto-awesome photos from my backups. How do I delete en masse all the stories created by G+ from these backups? I can delete them one at a time, but that is a pain.

There are notifications for each story (also annoying), but the real problem is that I don't want to use these stories and never asked for them. I checked all the settings of my G+ Android, G+ Desktop, etc. and all of them have disabled "Auto awesome" which, according to [Google's help page](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/6029803?hl=en), prevents stories from being created:

> **Stop receiving Stories**
>
> You can prevent new stories from being created by turning off Auto Awesome

As I said, auto-awesome is deactivated (I checked desktop, iOS, Android versions of the app and this feature was never activated) but the stories keep on coming. Many of them are nonsense, e.g., "Friday afternoon in X" where "X" is my hometown and they're just some photos I took of a receipt from Costco or of my son wearing a new hat. Basically useless stuff I never asked for.

This smells of the [G+ instant upload annoyance I already experienced once](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28529/how-to-delete-all-of-the-instant-upload-photos-on-google) (shame on me for falling twice into a G+ photo backup trap?). #ironic